# What database can wordpress use ?

Tags: database, wordpress

I want to know whether I can use another database engines with Wordpress, other than MySQL or not.

I found this post https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases that says no, I can't.

But then I found this one that says I can use SQL Server : http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server and another that says I can use Oracle.

I'm a bit comfused

Comment: http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ says you should have MySQL. Period. Then you could probably tweak it to use any SQL db but not out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we can use other RDBMS other than **MySql**. We can use **MSSQL**, **Oracle** and **PostgreSQL**

There is a Database Abstraction Layer present which helps you do this by choosing the driver for which you want to use

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has already been answered, but perhaps someone will find this useful. If you're interested in running MSSQL, I would suggest trying [Project Nami](https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami). It's an up-to-date fork of WordPress that has fewer limitations than the DB Abstraction plugin.